# How to convert array list to list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

**I have an array as :**

```
y_array= [array( [[1.008],[2.000],[5.8756],..[8.343]]),array([[3.5666],[2.5554],[5.888],...[3.2112]])]
```

I wish to display a list as an output,but what I actually get is an array list.

**My output is:**

```
 y= [array([[1.008],[2.000],[5.8756],..[8.343]])
```

**My expected output is**

```
y=[[1.008],[2.000],[5.8756],..[8.343]]
```

**What I have tried is:**

```
   checked_list=[['Col-2', 'Col-3']]

    for j in range(len(checked_list)):
        y_values.append('y'+str(j+1))

    for k in range(len(y_values)):          
        ydat = data[:, k + 1].reshape(m, 1)
        y_array.append(ydat)

    splitArraylist=[[y] for y in y_array]
    for i in range(len(checked_list)):
        self.XY(splitArraylist[i])

def XY(self,y):      

    print(y)
```

How to get list as an output instead of arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is a list of lists, and the inner list has only 1 element, so use it's index to access the inner list, and then using list comprehension, convert each sublist to a list

```
import numpy as np
y = [np.array([[1.008], [2.000], [5.8756],[8.343]])]

#Convert each sublist in y[0] to a list
res = [list(item) for item in y[0]]
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
[[1.008], [2.0], [5.8756], [8.343]]
```

Comment: Nah. y[0] is still an array. The OP clearly states "I wish to dispaly a list as an output,"

Comment: Damn! Should have read the question better! I fixed it Thanks @Sheldore Please take a look and consider upvoting if it is fine?